# Spring Rich Client Toolbar Menu won't show

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have downloaded Spring Rich Client 1.1.0 from sourceforge and wired up all the beans. When I run the app, I see a pane but no menubar. No warnings or errors in the console.

Here are the menuBar beans:

```
<bean id="menuBar" class="org.springframework.richclient.command.CommandGroupFactoryBean" >
    <property name="members">
        <list>
            <ref bean="userManagementMenu" />       
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="userManagementMenu" class="org.springframework.richclient.command.CommandGroupFactoryBean" >
    <property name="members">
        <list>
            <ref bean="userCommand"/>
            <ref bean="userGroupCommand"/>
            <value>separator</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fd1" class="org.springframework.richclient.command.config.CommandFaceDescriptor">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="hello"/>
</bean>
<bean id="fd2" class="org.springframework.richclient.command.config.CommandFaceDescriptor">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="there"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userCommand" class="org.springframework.richclient.command.support.WidgetViewCommand">
 <property name="widgetViewDescriptorId" value="userView" />
 <property name="faceDescriptor" ref="fd1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userGroupCommand" class="org.springframework.richclient.command.support.WidgetViewCommand">
 <property name="widgetViewDescriptorId" value="userGroupView" />
  <property name="faceDescriptor" ref="fd2"/>
</bean>
```

And it is called as follows:

```
<bean id="lifecycleAdvisor" class="org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationLifecycleAdvisor">
    <property name="windowCommandBarDefinitions" value="ctx/commands.xml"/>
    <property name="windowCommandManagerBeanName" value="windowCommandManager"/>
    <property name="startingPageId" value="userGroupView"/>
    <property name="menubarBeanName" value="menuBar"/>
</bean>
```

Here are the view related beans:

```
<bean name="userView" scope="prototype" class="org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultViewDescriptor">
    <property name="viewClass" value="com.mycom.views.UserGroupView"/>
</bean>
<bean name="userGroupView" scope="prototype" class="org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultViewDescriptor">
<property name="viewClass" value="com.mycom.views.UserGroupView"/>

</bean>
```

Here are the misc beans

```
<bean id="serviceLocator" class="org.springframework.richclient.application.ApplicationServicesLocator">
    <property name="applicationServices" ref="applicationServices" />
</bean>

<bean id="applicationServices"
    class="org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices" />

 <bean id="applicationEventMulticaster"
    class="org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster" />
<bean id="application" class="org.springframework.richclient.application.Application">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="applicationDescriptor"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="lifecycleAdvisor"/>
 </bean>
```

```
    <bean id="applicationDescriptor" class="org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationDescriptor">
    <property name="version" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="buildId" value="20060408-001"/>
</bean>


<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is the UserGroupView:

```
package com.mycom.views;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.springframework.richclient.application.support.AbstractView;

public class UserGroupView extends AbstractView {
private JTextField field = new JTextField();
private JLabel lbl = new JLabel("UserGroup:");

public JComponent createControl() {
    JPanel view = new JPanel();
    view.add(lbl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    view.add(field,  BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return view;
}
}
```

Here is the code for UserView

```
package com.mycom.views;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

 import javax.swing.JComponent;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.springframework.richclient.application.support.AbstractView;

public class UserView extends AbstractView {
private JTextField field = new JTextField();
private JLabel lbl = new JLabel("User:");

public JComponent createControl() {
    JPanel view = new JPanel();
    view.add(lbl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    view.add(field,  BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return view;
}
}
```

Here is the console log:

Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@45283ce2: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@45283ce2]; startup date [Wed Feb 24 09:21:13 PST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/appbundle.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/application.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/commands.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/models.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/filters.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/filterforms.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/editors.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/forms.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/dataproviders.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/services.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/views.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@45283ce2]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@591f989e
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@591f989e: defining beans [serviceLocator,applicationServices,applicationEventMulticaster,application,windowCommandManager,lifecycleAdvisor,applicationDescriptor,messageSource,menuBar,userManagementMenu,fd1,fd2,userCommand,userGroupCommand,baseModel,user,userGroup,userFilter,userGroupFilter,abstractFilterForm,userFilterForm,userGroupFilterForm,abstractDataEditor,userDataEditor,userGroupDataEditor,abstractForm,userForm,userGroupForm,abstractDataProvider,userDataProvider,userGroupDataProvider,userService,userGroupService,userView,userGroupView]; root of factory hierarchy
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$8 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: CommandConfigurer
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$7 build
INFO: No object configurer bean Id has been set; configuring defaults.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$4 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: CommandServices
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userCommand.foreground]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userCommand.background]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userCommand.caption]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userCommand.description]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$10 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: IconSource
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$9 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: ImageSource
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [org/springframework/richclient/image/images.properties]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userCommand.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userCommand.large.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userCommand.foreground]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userCommand.background]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userCommand.caption]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userCommand.description]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userCommand.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userCommand.large.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userGroupCommand.foreground]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userGroupCommand.background]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userGroupCommand.caption]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userGroupCommand.description]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userGroupCommand.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userGroupCommand.large.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userGroupCommand.foreground]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userGroupCommand.background]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userGroupCommand.caption]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userGroupCommand.description]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userGroupCommand.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userGroupCommand.large.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userManagementMenu.foreground]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userManagementMenu.background]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationObjectConfigurer loadMessage
INFO: The message source is unable to find message code [userManagementMenu.description]. Ignoring and returning null.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userManagementMenu.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.image.DefaultIconSource getIcon
INFO: No image resource found for icon with key 'userManagementMenu.large.icon'; returning a  icon.
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.ApplicationLauncher displaySplashScreen
INFO: No splash screen bean found to display. Continuing...
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$25 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: ApplicationWindowFactory
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationWindowFactory createApplicationWindow
INFO: Creating new DefaultApplicationWindow
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationLifecycleAdvisor$CommandBarApplicationContext@21cf5ed5: display name [org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationLifecycleAdvisor$CommandBarApplicationContext@21cf5ed5]; startup date [Wed Feb 24 09:21:13 PST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@45283ce2
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ctx/commands.xml]
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.richclient.application.config.DefaultApplicationLifecycleAdvisor$CommandBarApplicationContext@21cf5ed5]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5853b97a
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5853b97a: defining beans [menuBar,userManagementMenu,fd1,fd2,userCommand,userGroupCommand]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@591f989e
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$26 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: ApplicationPageFactory
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationPageFactory createApplicationPage
INFO: Creating new DefaultApplicationPage
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.core.LabeledObjectSupport getDisplayName
INFO: This labeled object's display name is not configured; returning 'displayName'
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:13 AM org.springframework.richclient.core.LabeledObjectSupport getDisplayName
INFO: This labeled object's display name is not configured; returning 'displayName'
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:14 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$2 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: MenuFactory
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:14 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$3 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: ButtonFactory
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:14 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$5 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: ComponentFactory
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:14 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$19 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: ViewDescriptorRegistry
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:14 AM org.springframework.richclient.application.support.DefaultApplicationServices$27 build
INFO: Creating default service impl: PageComponentPaneFactory
Feb 24, 2016 9:21:14 AM org.springframework.richclient.core.LabeledObjectSupport getDisplayName
INFO: This labeled object's display name is not configured; returning 'displayName'
Feb 24, 2016 9:33:19 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@45283ce2: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@45283ce2]; startup date [Wed Feb 24 09:21:13 PST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 24, 2016 9:33:19 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@591f989e: defining beans [serviceLocator,applicationServices,applicationEventMulticaster,application,windowCommandManager,lifecycleAdvisor,applicationDescriptor,messageSource,menuBar,userManagementMenu,fd1,fd2,userCommand,userGroupCommand,baseModel,user,userGroup,userFilter,userGroupFilter,abstractFilterForm,userFilterForm,userGroupFilterForm,abstractDataEditor,userDataEditor,userGroupDataEditor,abstractForm,userForm,userGroupForm,abstractDataProvider,userDataProvider,userGroupDataProvider,userService,userGroupService,userView,userGroupView]; root of factory hierarchy

The label and text box are displayed, but there is no tool bar. Any idea why? Thanking you in anticipation.

[image]

```
package com.mycom.form;


import com.mycom.model.User;

import org.springframework.richclient.form.builder.FormLayoutFormBuilder;

public class UserForm extends AbstractForm{

public UserForm(String formId, User user) throws Exception{
    super(formId, user);
}

protected void addComponents(FormLayoutFormBuilder builder){

    super.addComponents(builder);
    builder.addPropertyAndLabel("dateOfBirth");
    builder.nextRow();

    builder.addPropertyAndLabel("userGroup");
}
}
```

AbstractForm code:

```
package com.mycom.form;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;

import com.mycom.model.BaseModel;

import org.springframework.binding.form.FieldMetadata;
import org.springframework.richclient.form.FormModelHelper;
import org.springframework.richclient.form.TabbedForm;
import org.springframework.richclient.form.builder.FormLayoutFormBuilder;

public class AbstractForm extends TabbedForm{

private String tabName;

public AbstractForm(String formId, BaseModel baseModel) throws Exception{
    super(FormModelHelper.createFormModel(baseModel, formId));
}

protected Tab[] getTabs(){

    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout("default, 3dlu, fill:pref:nogrow", "default");
    FormLayoutFormBuilder builder = new FormLayoutFormBuilder(getBindingFactory(), layout);
    addComponents(builder);
    return new Tab[] {new Tab(getTabName(), builder.getPanel())};
}

protected void addComponents(FormLayoutFormBuilder builder){

    builder.addPropertyAndLabel("id");
    builder.nextRow();

    JComponent nameComponent = builder.addPropertyAndLabel("name")[1];
    builder.nextRow();

    FieldMetadata idMetaData = getFormModel().getFieldMetadata("id");
    idMetaData.setReadOnly(true);

    setFocusControl(nameComponent);
}

protected String getTabName(){
    return tabName;
}

public void setTabName(String tabName) {
    this.tabName = tabName;
}
}
```

Form beans:

```
<bean name="abstractForm" scope="prototype" abstract = "true">
    <property name= "tabName" value="Detail" />
</bean>

<bean name="userForm" scope="prototype" class="com.mycom.form.UserForm">
    <constructor-arg index = "0" value="userForm" />  
    <constructor-arg index = "1" ref="user" />
    <property name= "tabName" value="User Detail" />
</bean>
```

Comment: http://www.doclo.be/lieven/SpringRichClient.pdf has some detail but they are using org.springframework.richclient.command.* defined commands. I need customized commands that merely change the view as given here http://www.javabeat.net/introduction-to-spring-rich-client/. The latter URL does not provide the classes for beans (class attribute). So I wouldn't recommend it even though I started working with that as the basis. There is a NetBeans related tutorial that I didn't bother. I use eclipse mars. Thanks

Comment: How to display forms within tabs?